# Different google analytics tracking ID per subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

I created a new web property in my google analytics account. When I navigate to the Tracking Code of the property, the code looks like this:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX-1"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-1');
</script>
```

I have multiple clients and each client has their own subdomain on my site. Example:

```
subdomain1.mysite.com UA-XXXXXXXXX-1
subdomain2.mysite.com UA-XXXXXXXXX-2
subdomain3.mysite.com UA-XXXXXXXXX-3
```

And in my HTML, I want to load the tracking code that that particular client has given me (identified based on current subdomain).

My question is, is it safe to assume, that the tracking code script will be the same for all the properties (except of course the UA number)?

If so, I can simply change the UA number in the tracking code like so:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<%= current_client.google_analytics_code %>"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', '<%= current_client.google_analytics_code %>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't made any other changes/additions to the tracking script (like custom dimensions, anonymizers, linkers, etc.) that you don't want pushed to all the clients' subdomains, then it is safe for you to dynamically insert the UA account ID.

Have in mind though, that if you plan to have two UA codes on those subdomains (for ex. your roll-up and theirs for the subdomain), you should rename trackers and cookies to separate the tracking and don't mix the attribution information between the accounts.